# PHP - Why does including a function from another file fail?

Tags: php, function, include

I am trying to include a function from one PHP file into another and use the function with a parameter and get a return value. All is good until I run the function, where PHP dies. How can I fix this?

timestamp_reader.php:

```
<?php
function get_time($timestamp){
    $year = substr($timestamp, 0, 4);
    $month = substr($timestamp, 4, 2);
    if(substr($month, 0, 1) == "0")
        $month = substr($month, 1, 1);
    $day = substr($timestamp, 6, 2);
    if(substr($day, 0, 1) == "0")
        $day = substr($day, 1, 1);
    $hour = substr($timestamp, 8, 2);
    if(substr($hour, 0, 1) == "0")
        $hour = substr($hour, 1, 1);
    $hour = intval($hour);
    if($hour > 12){
        $hour = $hour - 12;
        $pm = true;
    }else $pm = false;
    $minute = substr($timestamp, 10, 2);
    if(substr($day, 0, 1) == "0")
    $day = substr($day, 1, 1);
    if($pm) $minute .= " PM";
    else $minute .= " AM";

    return $month . "/" . $day . "/" . $year . " " . $hour . ":" . $minute;
}
?>
```

And the file that I want access to this function (note, it is in a different directory):

```
...some PHP code before this...
include "/project/includes/timestamp_reader.php";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $msg = $row['message'];
    $timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
    $time = get_time($timestamp);
    echo "<p><center>" . $time . " " . $msg . "</center></p>";
}
```

I'd like to figure this out and use it for a variety of functions so I don't have to type them in every time if possible. Also, I need something similar for creating project-wide variables.

Anyway, thanks for any and all help!

Comment: and what is the error message ?

Comment: Looks like using `date()` and `strtotime()` would be a better idea here.

Comment: What's the error message?  PS, it'd probably be neater to do the time formatting in SQL in your `SELECT` statement rather than in PHP. (assuming you're using MySql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html )

Comment: Firefox tells me Error in parsing value for 'filter'. Declaration dropped. in error console.

Comment: @Richard , what has firefox's console to do with php errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the `date()` [function](http://php.net/date) within PHP?

For example,

```
$timestamp = "1316922240";
echo date("m-j-Y", $timestamp);
```

Will print out 09-24-2011 based on that time stamp for right now - if the timestamp was from yesterday, the date echo-ed will be yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

How about you avoid reinventing a wheel ? .. especially so misshapen one :

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score 0):

try with require(), it fails if the path is wrong, which I bet is the case.

Comment: As you are including a file with a function, `require_once()` would be preferable in this case.